Acceder a los valores de un Entry, Spinbox o Combobox de un toplevel desde otro toplevel o de la raiz
Tengo una ventana principal con el siguiente código
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
import VentanaSecundaria

def Contratar():

    VentanaSecundaria.Ventana_4_1()

def Cerrar():

    global Variable3 
    
    print(Variable3)

    Sc1.destroy()

Sc1=Tk()
Sc1.title("Pantalla principal. Sc1")
Sc1.resizable(True,True)
#Sc1.minsize(200,200)
Sc1.attributes('-fullscreen',False)

Duracion=Label(Sc1,text="Duracion",font="calibri 16 bold",justify=LEFT,padx=10,pady=10)
Duracion.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")

Per_Amortizacion=Spinbox(Sc1,font="calibri 16 bold",width=7,justify=RIGHT,from_=10,increment=1,to=50)
Per_Amortizacion.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="e")

Contratar=Button(Sc1,text='Contratar',command=Contratar,font="calibri 16 bold",bg="grey70",pady=20,padx=20)
Contratar.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="n")

Cerrar=Button(Sc1,text='Cerrar',command=Cerrar,font="calibri 16 bold",bg="grey70",pady=20,padx=20)
Cerrar.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=3,sticky="n")

Sc1.mainloop()

Tengo una ventana secundaria en la misma carpeta del archivo de la ventana anterior con el siguiente código
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

def Ventana_4_1():

    def Obtener_Valores():

        global Variable3

        Variable3=Per_Amortizacion_1.get()

        return Variable3

    def Cerrar():

        Sc4_1.destroy()

    global Variable3

    Variable3=None

    Sc4_1=Toplevel()
    Sc4_1.title("Pantalla Secundaria Sc4_1")
    Sc4_1.resizable(True,True)
    Sc4_1.minsize(200,200)
    Sc4_1.attributes('-fullscreen',False)

    Duracion=Label(Sc4_1,text="Duracion",font="calibri 16 bold",justify=LEFT,padx=10,pady=10)
    Duracion.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")

    Per_Amortizacion_1=Spinbox(Sc4_1,font="calibri 16 bold",width=7,justify=RIGHT,from_=10,increment=1,to=50)
    Per_Amortizacion_1.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="e")

    Cerrar=Button(Sc4_1,text='Cerrar',command=Cerrar,font="calibri 16 bold",bg="grey70",pady=20,padx=20)
    Cerrar.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=1,sticky="n")

    Obtener=Button(Sc4_1,text='Obtener',command=Obtener_Valores,font="calibri 16 bold",bg="grey70",pady=20,padx=20)
    Obtener.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=1,sticky="n")

Pues bien al accionar el boton Obtener en la ventana secundaria, inicializando la variable global Variable3, volviendo a la ventana principal y accionar el boton Cerrar, intentando imprimir la variable global Variable3, sale el error "NameError: name 'Variable3' is not defined"
¿Alquien puede dar una solución a este pobre principiante?
gracias

En Python las variables globales no se comportan como en otros lenguajes, en las que están disponibles durante toda la ejecución del programa desde cualquier parte. Los objetos están vinculados a variables/nombres que pertenecen a un espacio de nombres concreto. La palabra clave global se refiere al espacio de nombres del módulo actual, puedes importar una variable global de otro modulo, pero cada modulo tiene su namespace y su copia de la variable, reasignar un nuevo valor en uno no hace que el cambio se sincronice en el otro.
Hay formas de hacerlo funcionar, lo menos grotesco es hacer uso del namespace del módulo importado, las variables globales no dejan de ser otro atributo más del módulo:
modulo_con_global.py
variable = 0

def sumar_siete():
    global variable
    variable += 7

main.py
import modulo_con_global

print(modulo_con_global.variable)
modulo_con_global.sumar_siete()
print(modulo_con_global.variable)
modulo_con_global.variable = 14
modulo_con_global.sumar_siete()
print(modulo_con_globala.variable)

No obstante, simple y llanamente, no uses variables globales si no hay una muy buena razón para ello y no existe otra forma más conveniente. En general evita el uso de variables globales en cualquier lenguaje, otra cosa son las constantes.
Hay muchas formas de pasar la información, una muy simple en tu caso es crear una IntVar y pasarla como argumento a la función constructora de la ventana secundaria.
Muchos de los "malos usos" que se les suele dar a las variables globales se pueden resolver simplemente pasando argumentos a las funciones o retornando desde ella lo necesario, usando POO y usar atributos de instancia, etc.
Aparte de evitar el uso de variables globales, un par de recomendaciones:

Sigue en lo posible las convenciones de estilo de PEP-8, ayudan mucho a la legibilidad del código.

Evita el "star import" (from modulo import *). Es otra muy mala practica en general, contamina el espacio de nombres, dificulta la legibilidad del código, es fuente de errores al solapar identificadores entre namespaces inadvertidamente, dificulta el trabajo de los linters, etc...


Con ello en cuenta, tu código podría quedar:
import tkinter as tk
from ventana_secundaria import crear_ventana_sc4


def contratar():
    crear_ventana_sc4(sc1, variable)

def cerrar(): 
    print(variable.get())
    sc1.destroy()

sc1 = tk.Tk()
sc1.title("Pantalla principal. Sc1")
sc1.resizable(True, True)
#sc1.minsize(200, 200)
sc1.attributes('-fullscreen', False)

variable = tk.IntVar()

tk.Label(
    sc1,
    text="Duracion",
    font="calibri 16 bold",
    justify=tk.LEFT,
    padx=10,
    pady=10
).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

per_amortizacion_1 = tk.Spinbox(
    sc1,
    font="calibri 16 bold",
    width=7,
    justify=tk.RIGHT,
    from_=10,
    increment=1,
    to=50
)
per_amortizacion_1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

tk.Button(
    sc1,
    text='Contratar',
    command=contratar,
    font="calibri 16 bold",
    bg="grey70",
    pady=20,
    padx=20
).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="n")

tk.Button(
    sc1,
    text='Cerrar',
    command=cerrar,
    font="calibri 16 bold",
    bg="grey70",
    pady=20,
    padx=20
).grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky="n")

sc1.mainloop()

y ventana_secundaria.py:
import tkinter as tk


def crear_ventana_sc4(root, variable):

    sc4_1 = tk.Toplevel(root)
    sc4_1.title("Pantalla Secundaria Sc4_1")
    sc4_1.resizable(True, True)
    sc4_1.minsize(200, 200)
    sc4_1.attributes('-fullscreen', False)

    tk.Label(
        sc4_1,
        text="Duracion",
        font="calibri 16 bold",
        justify=tk.LEFT,
        padx=10,
        pady=10
    ).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

    spin_box = tk.Spinbox(
        sc4_1,
        font="calibri 16 bold",
        width=7,
        justify=tk.RIGHT,
        from_=10,
        increment=1,
        to=50
    )
    spin_box.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

    tk.Button(
        sc4_1,
        text='Cerrar',
        command=sc4_1.destroy,
        font="calibri 16 bold",
        bg="grey70",
        pady=20,
        padx=20
    ).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky="n")

    tk.Button(
        sc4_1,
        text='Obtener',
        command=lambda: variable.set(spin_box.get()),
        font="calibri 16 bold",
        bg="grey70",
        pady=20,
        padx=20
    ).grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky="n")

